# How to find the Docker alpine version for a golang tag?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I have a Dockerfile with

```
FROM golang:1.17.3-alpine as builder
```

How to find out what version of alpine this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
docker run --rm golang:1.17.3-alpine cat /etc/os-release
```